# What is SSL Connection and how to use it in windows 8 Metro app?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm going to create a XMPP client for Windows 8 Metro App, i need to enable socket connection. I don't know about ssl connection and how to use it. the metro app is limited in its library.

There are 2 socket connections in the metro app,

```
    StreamSocket
    DatagramSocket
```

Which one is suite for ssl connection and anyone say me how to use that to enable it. .

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Net 2.0 a class named SslStream has been created.
You can authenticate your server and optionally the client via SSL-security protocol (Secure Socket Layer)

Look for details and sample code here at:

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx

But you need your own SSL-certificate!

For more info about SSL look here:
http://www.anything-it.com.au/4-tafe/simplessl.htm